# How to extract information out from event.data in django channels

Tags: javascript, django, websocket, django-channels

Hello i have some trouble trying to extract and transfer data from my backend to my front end.

Here is my code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var loc = window.location
var wsStart = 'ws://'
if (loc.protocol == 'https'){
  wsStart = 'wss://'
}
var endpoint = wsStart + loc.host + loc.pathname
var socket = new WebSocket(endpoint)
socket.onmessage = function(e){
  var x = e.data;
  console.log("message",e);
  badgeCreate();
  console.log(x.message);
  alert(x);

}
socket.onopen = function(e){  
  console.log("open",e)
  console.log(e.error)
}
socket.onerror = function(e){
  console.log("error",e)
}
socket.onclose = function(e){
  console.log("close",e)
}    
</script>
```

this is a relevant bit of my consumers.py:

```
    async def user_notification (self, event):
        close_old_connections()
        print('user noti gets called')
        await self.send_json({
            'event': 'notification',
            'data': {
                'event_type': 'notification',
                'notification_pk': event['notification_pk'],
                'link': event['link'],
                'date_created': event['date_created'],
                'message': event['message'],
            }
        })
        print(event)
```

This is printed on my alert box:

```
{"event": "notification", "data": {"event_type": "notification", "notification_pk": 64, "link": "test", "date_created": "2020-01-23 05:27:08", "message": "wqe"}}
```

Changing `x=e.data` to `x= e.data.message` results in it being undefined. Does anyone know what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a while since you asked the question and the problem has probably been solved long time ago. So for all the people that are looking for the solution, data shall be parsed with JSON.parse(). I tried sending data back and forth and all of three solutions presented below turned out to be good.

```
socket.onmessage = function(event){
  var x = JSON.parse(event.data)
  console.log(x.message)

}
```

ES6 version:

```
socket.onmessage = (event) => {
  let x = JSON.parse(event.data)
  console.log(x.message)
}
```

Event listeners:

```
socket.addEventListener("error", (event) => {
  let x = JSON.parse(event.data)
  console.log(x.message)
});
```

And here is my function inside class inherited from AsyncJsonWebsocketConsumer:

```
async def hello(self, event):
    await self.send_json(
        {
            "type": "hello",
            "message": event["message"]
        }
    )
```